# Are WordPress.com questions welcome?

Tags: discussion, scope

This was [discussed in the definition phase of this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500?phase=definition), and [now again when we are defining the FAQ](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-should-our-faq-contain/42#42).

Since discussing it in the comments might be a bit limiting, I pose it as a separate question: **Would allowing questions about WordPress.com be beneficial to this site and community, or not?**

#### Example wordpress.com Questions

- [How to disable Wordpress.com default feed and use feedburner feed in place of that?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/921/how-to-disable-wordpress-com-default-feed-and-use-feedburner-feed-in-place-of-tha)

Comment: Ivo Flipse (WebApps) was worried that we might get Math Overflow syndrome and close questions too fast if they are too basic.

Answer (score 6):

I think we should allow *selected* types of questions about WordPress.com.  There are many questions that are applicable to both, and often the answer is "*Switch to Self-hosting*". I'd hate to keep the people that need to hear that message from hearing it by barring them from the door.

I would instead suggest we delineate what types of question are and are not appropriate and we maintain and add to that list over time.

On the flip site, if everyone disagrees with this we need to work hard on our name so that it will be obvious that this site is not for *WordPress Answers* but instead ***Self-hosted*** WordPress Answers.

JMTCW.

-Mike

Comment: I very strongly believe that this is the best solution presented thus far.  Obviously we don't want the completely naive/ignorant folks asking how to get started at with wordpress.com, but there will almost certainly be value in both questions and answers coming from people who don't self-host.

Comment: *@MikeSchinkel* just to say I like your answer.

Answer (score 5):

**I think we should accept all questions related to WordPress, self-hosted or not.** If we don't, other sites (most likely Web Apps and Pro Webmasters) will accept these questions, but [they won't necessarily make the distinction between .com or .org](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-should-we-do-with-wordpress-questions-and-how-tag-them/204#204), and *start treading on our domain*.

If we want this site to grow (and survive the beta phase), we should have a clear scope so other sites know we exist *and refer questions to us*. If they start accepting and answering WordPress.com questions, the barrier to answering self-hosted WordPress questions will be lower. So for this reason, **I think accepting WordPress.com questions will be beneficial to our site and community.** We don't want to [confuse users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/where-should-i-ask-wordpress-questions): if your question is about WordPress, come to us.

The current status on other sites is:

- Web Apps: [41 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) (9th popular tag), [.com and .org approved on Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-should-we-do-with-wordpress-questions-and-how-tag-them)
- Pro Webmasters: [25 questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) (4th popular tag), [.org somehow approved on Meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/ok-i-love-wordpress-as-much-as-the-next-guy-but-is-pro-webmasters-really-the-ri)
- Stack Overflow: [3013 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress)
- Server Fault: [158 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)
- Super User: [16 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), [none accepted](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/920/questions-about-wordpress-on-super-user)

*If you want to downvote this opinion, please leave a comment so we know why and can have a discussion.*

Comment: How about if I **"up vote"** instead? :)

Comment: BTW, I reserve the right to change my up vote to a down vote it the site floods with really stoopid questions. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Wordpress.com questions should be gracefully redirected to better places.**

Questions regarding wordpress.com can normally not be answered because users over there have very limit interaction with the software compared to standard wordpress users.

That's why the wordpress.com site attracts absolute noobs (like me) who host their blog there because they just don't want to deal with anything technical.

It would flood the Q&A site with end-user questions and degrade the user experience of both, the askers and those who answer questions.

The first place for wordpress.com users to propose questions - if they have some - is [the support of wordpress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/). Additionally, those questions can just be asked on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). WebApps is more suited for it anyway.

Comment: Also read [the related discussion on WebApps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-should-we-do-with-wordpress-questions-and-how-tag-them), where the most popular answer even suggested allowing questions about self-hosted installs, since WordPress is becoming more and more a web app (no FTP required for plugin installation, ...).

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - Hey cool that means we can concentrate more on administration and programming stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

As discussed [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-should-our-faq-contain/42#42), I agree that WordPress.com questions are a bit off topic.  Yes, they deal with WordPress, but in a completely unique environment than just about any that use the .org version of WordPress.  There are things you can do on .com that you can't do with .org and vice-versa ... supporting both communities will just create a very confused user base.

I'd be more apt to direct WordPress.com questions either back to Automattic (since the hosting company should be responsible for support in the first place) or to [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).