# Please update the FAQ to indicate the status of Wordpress.com questions here

Tags: feature-request

Your FAQ is a contract with users: This is what we accept, this is what we don't. At the moment, it doesn't address the issue of WP.com and WP.org.

I understand that the status of Wordpress.com questions is currently [vague](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/are-wordpress-com-questions-welcome). However, I see that many of these dotcom questions get migrated or closed, so the site is effectively rejecting them. And while the opinions on that meta thread are spread out, it looks like the community wants to exclude them. Well and good, but if this site is going to continue doing this, I'd ask that you please update [the FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) to indicate the ambiguity.

As it stands, when the site rejects such a question, it comes across as cliqueish and exclusionary to new Wordpress.com users who may not even be aware of the difference between .com and .org. Indicating this in the FAQ might help avoid confusion.

[Hakre's meta answer](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/57/1243) is an excellently worded clear explanation of the issues involved, and shortening it down could serve as a template for some FAQ text. Here's my attempt at an FAQ addition, based on that meta post:

> Wordpress comes in the self-hosted variety (referred to as Wordpress**.org**) and the free, online web version (Wordpress**.com**). If you haven't set Wordpress up on server space, you're probably using Wordpress.com. Users of Wordpress.com have very limit interaction with the software compared to standard wordpress users. These questions can be better answered at [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) or on the [Wordpress.com support site](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/).

Answer (score 4):

The FAQs have been updated with a brief explanation of where .COM users can go to get support.  And remember, we don't close/migrate every .COM question.  Some of them definitely belong here.  But any specific user support questions, account questions, etc are better directed to WordPress.com directly.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see it in the FAQ. Which section is it in?

Comment: Had you run this by WebApps mods that they are ok with such questions that we pointed to them in this FAQ update?

Comment: Ran this by them a few weeks ago actually in chat.  They were migrating WP.com questions here so I had a long discussion with them about where WP.com questions belonged.

Comment: @neilfein On http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq at the bottom of the "Note that we do not handle" section.

Comment: Do you mean where it says "blogging and managing sites in general"? Users new to Wordpress **will not understand that this means them.** I *really* think you need to spell this out.

Comment: @neilfein No, the 3rd list item "regarding WordPress.com support issues"