# Are WordPress VIP Questions Not Welcome?

Tags: discussion

I recently experienced an import issue on a VIP instance and, after taking steps to log the issue with my project team, thought I'd reach out to the community: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55224/wordpress-vip-import-breaks-post-to-category-mappings The first comment and accompanying downvote seem to indicate that VIP inquiries are unwelcome.  What's the verdict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress VIP questions are, in my opinion, along the same vein as WordPress.com support questions.  You're dealing with a premium system that has its own support mechanisms and which uses custom code that the majority of us do not have access to.

We discussed the same issue with [WordPress.com questions](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/are-wordpress-com-questions-welcome) specifically.  The gist of the discussion came down to:

> If your question works for both WordPress.com and self-hosted WordPress blogs, then it's allowed. But if it's specific to WordPress.com *only* then it's off-topic for this site.

As a result, we added the following to our official FAQ:

> Note that we **do not** handle questions:
>
> - **regarding WordPress.com support issues**
>
>   - setup, feature, account, and other user support issues - *try WordPress.com support*
>   - questions regarding the use of WordPress.com - *try WebApps*

Comment: Thank you.  It appears that my question is off-topic for WPSE. I will remove it.  Cheers~

Answer (score 3):

I would reason same logic as for wordpress.com question applies. While it's not always offtopic, there just aren't much insight and suggestions that can be provided in most cases.

What do you think is best possible answer here? Other than "this is [not] known bug" from someone involved with VIP I don't see what else might be said. And it's unlikely that anything said will be actionable since it doesn't seem to be interface issue and there is no access to code (ehm, or is there?).

Comment: Someone who had experienced this issue could corroborate.  Someone who had successfully completed a similar import and did *not* experience this issue could provide their workflow.  Someone who had heard of this issue could weigh in with a known (to them) workaround.

Comment: @Andrew I just find the probability of someone being experienced with VIP and this issue and coming up onto your question and being able to suggest actionable solution very unlikely in this case.

Comment: So it seems.  I spend most of my time on SO, so I was not sure what percentage of the userbase of WPSE could relate to my issues.  As most of my clients are using VIP, I will refrain from bringing up platform-specific questions in the future.  As advised above, I understand that my question was off-topic for WPSE, and have deleted it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no verdict. Note that your question is still open; there wasn’t even a close vote. Anybody can write an answer.

There are other problems with your question:

- You don’t explain what the “WordPress VIP backoffice” is. No, that’s not obvious for everyone. I think you’re talking about a Pro account on WordPress.com? If so, good answer are not easy because they run a customized variant of WordPress and you have no access to the real code.
- There is no debug information in your question, not even a hint of research effort. If you move your mouse over the down arrow, you’ll see that as a reason to click it.

And really … *one* downvote is nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I brought it up on Meta, because I wasn't sure if I was outside the boundaries of WPSE.  I checked out the custom code version from the SVN repo to test locally, but did not experience the same issue.  I have updated the question to provide more information, as you suggested.